# How does SO remove HTML tags from questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, markdown, design, editor

I am curious how SO goes about removing HTML tags from posts. I just started using their MarkdownSharp project. By default MarkdownSharp encodes any HTML within code blocks like this:

```
<span style="color: red;">I am HTML</span>
```

But if I do the same thing outside of a code block it simply doesn't show up at all:

I am HTML <- tags are removed.

But they have whitelisted certain tags for basic markup, like the header tags:

`<h1>test</h1>`

## test

I can also type HTML entities like `&gt;` doesn't get re-encoded, it will actually show up as a >

I'm sure the tags that get removed are being removed BEFORE the content is passed to markdown, as markdown generated HTML tags would likely be removed if this tag removal code was run after markdown handled it.

Does anyone know how SO accomplishes this, and if it is code that is available to use? Alternatives are acceptable also. I'm hoping to find something in C# as my project is C# ASP.NET MVC 3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure why I get close votes, I feel like I was very specific and clear. If you have an issue please comment and let me know instead of just voting to close with no reason why.

Comment: It's because this question belongs on meta; it's a great question though.

Comment: It's getting **close** votes because this belongs to **meta** since it's related to inner workings of stackoverflow.

Comment: The 2 close votes cite "off topic". It doesn't seem such a bad question to me. I think it would be better if you asked how you could do it in your setting rather than how SO does it.

Comment: The close menu lists a bunch of reasons. People have to pick one of them.

Comment: Well I didn't think it was specifically related to SO since I am also welcoming alternatives that produce the same behavior and would like it for my own project. I am not discussing SO explicitly, just asking how it accomplishes a behavior. Seems a programming question to me.

Comment: @Chevex: It does seem programmer's question but you should rephrase it differently. You shouldn't be asking how stackoverflow does it, but that you're using the markdown editor and would like to accomplish certain things that don't work as intended out of the box. You can reference that stackoverflow does it this and that way, that you'd like to accomplish as well. But don't ask how stackoverflow's doing it. It will migrate to meta.

Comment: @Chevex: And don't get angry or annoyed because of it. You will likely get better answers rephrasing it anyway. Everything's for the better.

Comment: My being "angry or annoyed" is an assumption on your part. Reposted with note of clarification. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379469/how-does-so-remove-html-tags-from-questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They use the [HtmlSanitzer written by Jeff Atwood](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html).